# How do I install PostgreSQL version 14 on Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: postgresql

Ubuntu 20.04 only gave me the obsolete PostgreSQL 12. After upgrading to "21.04 (Hirsute Hippo)" I got version 13. How do I install the latest version (14)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the instructions on the [Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt):

```
sudo apt install curl ca-certificates gnupg
curl https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/apt.postgresql.org.gpg >/dev/null
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install postgresql-14
```

This worked for me on *Ubuntu 21.04*, but note that older Ubuntu releases may not be supported.